# Process.Start not working to launch a .exe file

Tags: python, vb.net

So I'm coding a text spammer in python. The program is working fine when I launchit manually. I had the idea to create an interface for the spammer with a button to launch the program but I have a problem.
When I press the button, it says that it failed to execute my python script. Here's the code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Spammer\beemovie"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Spammer\spammer.exe"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I have a first button to open the file where you can put the text you want to spam. This button is working fine. The second button is to launch the script but it's not working.

**EDIT 1**

Here's the code of spammer.exe, it's in python.

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(5)
f = open("beemovie", 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Comment: What is `Button1` doing? What is `beemovie`? It doesn't look like an executable or a script, right? `Process.Start()` doesn't load anything. Maybe you wanted to combine the two things (`spammer.exe` and `beemovie`)? Why do you need a python script? Cannot you do the same thing in VB.Net?

Comment: ok so first of all, beemovie is just a file with no extension that contain the message you want to spam. Button1 is to open it to modify the message. I coded the program in python because i'm a python programmer and I don't know how to do this in VB.Net.

Comment: So, do you need to read and process the content of `beemovie` with `spammer.exe`? As already mentioned, `Process.Start()` doesn't *open* stuff, it can shell out a know file to the registered opener, e.g., if you start a `.txt` file, there's the chance that notepad.exe will be run to open that file. If you want to open `beemovie` with `spammer.exe`, pass that file as an [argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments) to the executable.

Comment: Why tag this question [tag:c#] when it has nothing to do with the question. Also, why did no one bother to edit the tags and remove it?

Comment: Oops, i'm sorry for the c# tag, it was accidental.

Comment: Also, I don't want to open beemovie using spammer.exe. It's just that spammer.exe read the file to spam it. Gonna post the code of spammer.exe to show you.

Comment: So, you either pass the file to open as an argument to your executable (already linked), so you can open it from the command line parameters, or you just set the [WorkingDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory) of the Process you start, so your executable will find the file in its current path. See how the Process and [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory) classes work.

Comment: Is spammer.exe actually packaged as an exe, or is it raw python code?  If it's a python file, you need to launch python with your script as an argument rather than launching the script itself.

Comment: @Lankymart perhaps the spamming inclination of the subject matter extends to SO tags too! :)